# Load asset in Laravel template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I try to load asset JS in tempalte blade:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/angular_my.js')}}"></script>
```

In console Chrome I get JS error:

```
 http://localhost/public/%7B%7B%20asset('js/angular_my.js')%7D%7D
```

If to show source HTML code I see:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/angular_my.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: Is your file named `X.blade.php`?

Comment: Problem was in `.blade` thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asset looks from `Public` folder. That is why your file should be in: `public/js/` directory. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was missing .blade at the end of the filename in my laravel store directory